# jQuery SerialScroll Not Working in Opera 10.63 (for me anyway)

Tags: jquery, opera, serialscroll

Hi I have created a gallery type page using jQuery Serial Scroll (http://bit.ly/adKZp2)

It's working fine on all the browsers I need except for Opera (I'm testing with Opera 10.63 on a mac).

I can't see anything wrong and I'm not getting any JS errors - it's driving me a little nuts. Time for some new eyes on the problem. I'm basically doing the same thing as the demo (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/) and it works but mine doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am hoping I am just missing something really simple.

Comment: Still no luck, if anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

@Jason  Hi, I also met this problem, I tried to check all the code one by one. finally, I find the most probable problem is in css. For example, If I change `li{list-style:none;}` in the demo code, it failed run in opera. I think the most problem is the space width between two items.